# How does server find browser without public IP in a lan via Websocket?

Tags: tcp, websocket

Browser can send a request to web server and get response, it is easy to understand because every domain does resolve to one or more public network IP, browser can find web servers via public network IP.
Some clients have public IP like PPPOE, so, when I establish a Websocket connection between browser and server, server can send data to browser on a device that owns a public network IP device, but not every client has public network IP.
My question is how does server find browser without public IP in a lan via Websocket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Part of the magic is [Network Address Translation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) and is performed by the routers between the server and the web browser's computer.

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is the `server` never has to find the `client` because once a browser sends a request to the server and a TCP connection is established, that connection can be maintained for as long as necessary.

The TCP protocol has the `keepalive` concept where every so often a peer sends a probe packet to the client with no data expecting and ACK packet in response. This way the connection remains alive despite network inactivity and can be terminated where peer does not reply.

The WebSocket Protocol, a TCP-based protocol also defines a similar concept `Ping/Pong` in which either of the peers can send a Ping probe on demand once a connection is established. The peer must respond to a Ping frame with a Pong frame as soon as is practical. This checks for dead peers, in which case the connection would be dead.

Comment: Also thank you for your answer, I am mainly confused about NAT part in v1bri's anwser.